# Arduino BLE Multiple Services with CurieBLE

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it doable to define multiple BLE service for Arduino with CurieBLE? Seems all relevant examples are using one service with multiple characteristics.

```
blePeripheral.addAttribute(xService);
blePeripheral.addAttribute(xCharacteristic);
```

I know there are blePeripheral.addAttribute, but is it valid and workable to call them and add multiple services?

Answer (score -1):

I have done it both ways.  When I add characteristics without the service, GATT still keeps them.  Download an analyzer for free and you'll see the service for the characteristic.